How to collect news using newspaper3k
I am trying to collect news using newspaper3k. I have succeeded doing this with most of the websites using the code below.
import newspaper
url = "https://www.sample.com"
website = newspaper.build(url, memoize_articles = False, MAX_SUMMARY = 300)
for article in website.articles:
    print(article.url)
    print(article.title)

However, there are some websites which this code doesn't work. For example, when I insert "https://www.bloomberg.com/search?query=gold" in the url, I get the results I want but when I insert "https://www.reuters.com/site-search/?query=gold" in the url, I see no results showing.
In order to find out the problem, I also run the code below and the result was "Number of articles found: 0".
import newspaper
url = "https://www.reuters.com/site-search/?query=wheat"
website = newspaper.build(url, memoize_articles=False)

print(f"Number of articles found: {len(website.articles)}")
for article in website.articles:
    print(article.url)
    print(article.title)

I don't know why the code is not able to recognize the articles with the 2nd url and how to fix the problem.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

The major web sites change their HTML on a regular basis.  The module has to be updated to keep up.  Check with the author.

Reuters is probably using JavaScript. When you make requests from a website you are only getting the text of the page before any scripts are run. If Reuters is populating it's page with JavaScript there won't be anything for you to get. You could use selenium instead, but then you are going to be locked to specific browser and can easily be tracked by that browser. Something easy you can do to check whether JavaScript is the problem is simply go visit the page with JavaScript turned off. If you don't see articles on the page, then you aren't going to be able to scrape them without JS.

I think the problem is that the newspaper module is unable to fetch content from the Reuters site, but it is hiding the error code. If you request the same URL with the requests module, you see:
>>> url = "https://www.reuters.com/site-search/?query=wheat"
>>> requests.get(url)
<Response [401]>

And if you use the more recently maintained newspaper4k module, you see:
>>> import newspaper
>>> url = "https://www.reuters.com/site-search/?query=wheat"
>>> website = newspaper.build(url, memoize_articles=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/newspaper/api.py", line 57, in build
    s.build(
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/newspaper/source.py", line 186, in build
    self.download()
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/newspaper/source.py", line 288, in download
    self.html = network.get_html(self.url, self.config)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/newspaper/network.py", line 242, in get_html
    raise ArticleException(
newspaper.exceptions.ArticleException: Http error when downloading https://www.reuters.com/site-search/?query=wheat. Status code: {status_code}

If you look at the content of the 401 error response using requests, it says:
Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker

It is unlikely that you will be able to scrape the Reuters site without using a Javascript-capable solution.
